Entering & Existing Transitions with React Native Reanimated
I have a pretty basic component which is just a banner that shows at the top of a form.  I have configured some entering and existing transitions that work as needed.  They look good for my use case so no issue there.
However, I am stuck on how to make the sibling components not collapse as the banner is "exiting".
My parent component is something like this:
Form.tsx
<View>
  <FeedbackBanner ... showBanner={showBanner} />
  
  ... other components
</View>

When I trigger the banner to hide by setting showBanner to false, the exiting transition below runs but the layout immediately shifts and the animation for existing is now behind the "other components".  What is the best way to ensure the entering / existing transitions are not hidden by the other components during a layout shift etc.?  Just starting to learn using react-native-reanimated and can't seem to figure out the best way in this use case.
FeedbackBanner.tsx
import { Pressable, View } from 'react-native';
import Typography from '../Typography';
import SVG from '@/assets/svg';
import Animated, {
  Easing,
  LinearTransition,
  SlideInLeft,
  SlideOutRight
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

type Props = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  onClosePress?: () => void;
  showBanner?: boolean;
};

const FeedbackBanner = ({ title, description, showBanner, onClosePress }: Props) => {
  if (!showBanner) return null;
  return (
    <Animated.View
      className="flex flex-row overflow-hidden rounded border border-Feedback-Error bg-Neutral-White dark:bg-Neutral-White"
      key={'feedback-banner'}
      exiting={SlideOutRight.duration(500).easing(Easing.ease)}
      entering={SlideInLeft.duration(500).easing(Easing.ease)}
    >
      <View className="h-[100%] w-[8px] bg-Feedback-Error dark:bg-Feedback-Error"></View>
      <View className="flex-1 flex-row justify-between gap-1 px-4 py-3">
        <View className="flex flex-col">
          <Typography font="inter-semiBold">{title}</Typography>
          <Typography className="!color-Neutral-Grey-80 dark:!color-Neutral-Grey-80">
            {description}
          </Typography>
        </View>

        <Pressable onPress={onClosePress}>
          <View>
            <SVG.Close
              className="fill-Neutral-Grey-90 dark:fill-Neutral-Grey-90"
              height={24}
              width={24}
            />
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default FeedbackBanner;

